# multi rabbitmq client / server with nodejs

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I'm quite new to Rabbitmq and I'm working on a system where a central router could receive a message from a client, route it to a target, and send the response to the resquestor client.

Basically, there are 3 modules, each one can send a message targeting another module. I'd like the message to have the following flow:

- module1 sends a message to the router
- the router sends the message to module3 (=module1's target)
- module3 process the message and send a response to the router
- router forward the response to module1 (the requestor)

RabbitMQ seems a good candidate to this but I'm not sure what is the best way to implement that. Would the REQ/REP approach more appropriate ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a classic case of RPC

This link explains in detail (with python) how RPC in RabbitMQ works. [RPC Client](https://github.com/rabbitinaction/sourcecode/blob/master/python/chapter-4/rpc_client.py) and [RPC Server](https://github.com/rabbitinaction/sourcecode/blob/master/python/chapter-4/rpc_server.py)

But basically, what will happen is, from your example above:

(From RPC Client)

Module1 will connect to the RabbitMQ broker (14/17), and declare an exclusive queue (24)
it will then create a basicproperties of your message and set the reply_to (26) (which is a queue name) and then publish the message into the exchange (28)

(From RPC Server)

Module 3, would subscribe to the queue which the message from Module1 would end up in and then start consuming from that queue (40) when a message is received (31) it will process it then republish the result setting the routing key to the reply_to (38) then your consumer (Module1) will need from consume from it (see rpc consumer line 42)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. In the case module1 is a web server that receive an HTTP request and needs to have something done on a worker before resending the request to the HTTP client, which approach would you recommend ? Does the req/rep on "per http request basis" is the best one ?

Comment: I don't know enough about node.js to answer that, and really it depends on what you're doing. Will the node.js 'server app' be both the producer and consumer of the queue? what you'd really want is to have your web page submit a 'job' to the server and then have it check the status, the ideal would have to have something like websockets so that your server can event back to the webpage without it having to make another request - is this something that node.js can do?